# How can you display array objects one at a time in a container in an endless loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to coding and would really appreciate some help.  I am trying to loop through an array and display its contents in a container, but all of the objects are remaining in the container and eventually the array is empty.  How can I display array objects one at a time and apply an infinite loop to the array?  I would like to be able to cycle through each of the items in the array one at a time so that they can be displayed in the container over and over again.   Here is the function I've come up with so far:

```
function next(){
    test[index].addTo(container).drag();
    index++;
    if (index > test.length-1)
    index = 0
};
```

Comment: More code might make things clearer.

Comment: Please provide the code necessary to produce the problem you describe. What is the container? What is `drag`? (is it relevant to the question?) What is `addTo`? How is `next` called?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to write the code, but here's my solution. I hope this is what you want to achieve.

```js
const itemArr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];

const listAllElements = () => {
    itemArr.map(item => {
        const paragraf = document.createElement("p");
        const content = document.createTextNode(`${item}`);
        paragraf.appendChild(content);

        const element = document.getElementById("itemList");
        element.appendChild(paragraf);
    });
}

listAllElements();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
}

#itemList{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 50px;
}

#itemList p{
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 25px 75px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
      <section id="itemList"></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also live on: https://jsfiddle.net/milanpanin/psgd8yu6/1/

The printout is done in a paragraph, but you can change it to whatever element you want.